# Why does the paper Layer Normalization discuss the invariance properties of different normalization schemes?

Tags: deep-learning, normalization

When I read Related Work part in the paper [Layer Normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06450.pdf), it just analyses its invariance properties and compares it with those of others normalization methods, like batch normalization. But this paper does not talk how this property effect the entire neural networks, like CNN or RNN, specifically. Can you tell me more details about the effects or importance of invariance properties of normalization in NN?

Answer (score 0):

These invariance properties means that the network is less brittle.

Invariance to the scaling and shifting of weights means that proper weight initialization is not as important. Invariance to the scaling and shifting of data means that one bad (too big, too small, etc.) batch of input from the previous layer don't ruin the next layer.

Before Batch Normalization came along, the network had to be initialized with small random weights, sometimes from a specific distribution. Batch normalization made networks more robust to sub-optimal initial weights.